# How to print captured group from regex with grep or sed command?

Tags: regex, typescript, sed, grep, refactoring

I'd like to get rid of redundant magic strings present in a legacy code:

```
      anchor: contentDefinitionHelper.toPatternFormField(
        fields,
        'anchor',
        defaultFormFields,
        attributeFields,
        displayFields,
      ),
      title: contentDefinitionHelper.toPatternTextFormField(
        fields,
        'brick_title',
        defaultFormFields,
        attributeFields,
        displayFields,
      ),
      descriptions: contentDefinitionHelper.toPatternTextsFormField(
        fields,
        'descriptions',
        defaultFormFields,
        attributeFields,
        displayFields,
      ),
    }
  },
  presenter: DescriptionsPatternPresenter,

  technicalName: 'block_descriptions',
```

Basically here, I'd like to collect `anchor`, `brick_title` and `descriptions`, but I don't want to catch `block_descriptions`. I'd like to do this from a grep or sed command.

The following regex looks to be what I want when I test it on Rege101 online: `contentDefinitionHelper\.toPattern.*Field\(\s+fields,\s+('[^']+')`

But when I turn it into a grep command, nothing shows up:

```
➜  grep -poE "contentDefinitionHelper\.toPattern.*Field\(\s+fields,\s+('[^']+')" src/admin/components/content-definition/patterns/descriptions/Descriptions.config.ts

➜
```

Possible output:

```
anchor
brick_title
descriptions
```

EDIT: I'am on a MacOS. From what I understand, grep and sed works differently on this system.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your required output from the sample input you have provided. Good luck.

Comment: I have added the expected output in the first question

Answer (score 1):

You may try this `gnu grep` command with `\G`:

```bash
set +H # disable history expansion
grep -zoP "(?:contentDefinitionHelper\.\w*|(?<!\A)\G)[^')]*\K'[^'()]+'.*\R" file |
tr -d "[',]"

anchor
brick_title
descriptions
```

[Check this demo for more details on regex](https://regex101.com/r/NjF7es/1)

Comment: i thought `OP` specifically mentioned not wanting `'block_descriptions'` as part of the outcome ?

Comment: Good catch. Even though demo was correct but I copy-pasted incorrect grep command due to history expansion issue. Correct it now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following GNU `awk` solution. Where I am setting RS value to  `contentDefinitionHelper[^\n]*\n([^\n]*\n){2}'` to get only lines which are required by OP. Then using RT and splitting its values into array arr and getting required results then.

```
awk -v RS=' contentDefinitionHelper[^\n]*\n([^\n]*\n){2}' '
RT && num=split(RT,arr,ORS){
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|,$/,"",arr[num-1])
  print arr[num-1]
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/contentDefinitionHelper/{:a;n;/^\s*('\''.*),.*/!ba;s//\1/p}' file
```

Match a line containing `contentDefinitionHelper` and the continue fetching lines until one that begins with a single quote and ends in a comma (ignoring leading white space) and print the non-white space result.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1** : ***muuuuuuch*** simpler approach (or save a few more bytes if you're comfortable with double quotes at the shell level :

```
gawk '!_<(NF *= !/:/)' OFS= FS='^[^\47]+\47|\47.+$'
mawk '!_<(NF *= !/:/)' OFS= FS="^[^']+'|'.+$"
```

> ---

no capturing groups needed at all

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk 'NF *= /:/ < (!_<NF)' FS='^[^\47]*\47|\47.*$' OFS=
> ```

---

```
or another similar approach
```

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk 'NF *= 3 == NF' FS='^[^\47]+\47|(.*:|\47).*$' OFS=
> ```

---

```
anchor
brick_title
descriptions
```